# Simultaneous double left click with two mouse pointers on GlovePie

Tags: mouse

I am new to GlovePie.
I created a second mouse that moves simultaneously with the first pointer while staying at a fixed distance. My intent is to get a left click from both pointers simultaneously, because my aim is to click on two buttons simultaneously.
Is it possible to do this?

The code I wrote, following the [developer's wiki](https://github.com/Ravbug/GlovePIE/wiki), is this:

```
Cursor2.PosX = Mouse.CursorPosX + 80
Cursor2.PosY = Mouse.CursorPosY + 0
Cursor2.LeftButton = Mouse.LeftButton
Cursor2.RightButton = Mouse.RightButton
```

Very simply. Moving works but simultaneous clicks don't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine found online the solution to my request, which I share here even if I cannot fully understand its code. For example: why there are two mouse (*mouse* and *mouse1*) and two cursor (*Cursor* and *Cursor2*)? 
So if any of you are able to comments the lines of code, I would be grateful to understand them!

```
mouse.Swallow = true
fakemouse.DirectInputX = mouse1.DirectInputX
fakemouse.DirectInputY = mouse1.DirectInputY

var.x1 = mouse1.cursorPosX
var.x2 = 350

mouse.LeftButton = mouse1.LeftButton

if !mouse1.LeftButton then
    Cursor2.PosX = var.x1 - var.x2
    Cursor2.PosY = mouse1.cursorPosY
endif

if mouse1.LeftButton then
    press mouse1.LeftButton
    wait 20ms
    release mouse1.LeftButton

    Cursor2.PosX = var.x1
    Cursor.PosX = var.x1 - var.x2

    press mouse1.LeftButton
    wait 20ms
    release mouse1.LeftButton

    Cursor2.PosX = var.x1
    Cursor.PosX = var.x1 + var.x2
endif
```